# Need help to replicate a document layout and substitute the values in the replicated document

Tags: azure, data-science, document, data-masking, azure-form-recognizer

Azure Form recognizer does not provide capability of training less than 5 documents in a group. For this reason, I have to replicate the documents available in the group and change their values so I can create a set of 5 documents. The files are in PNG/JPG format. Any help would be great in finding the right tool to do this.

Note: The layout changes by group

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer needs 5 documents to train a model, best is to use real documents to train the model so it fits the production scenario. If you need to create 5 PNG / JPG files from a single file you can use an image editor or even power point to place new text on the existing values as an additional layer or in power point as text boxes with white background and then save them as a new image. Old school way of creating sample documents but as it needs only 5 for train and then 1 or 2 for testing the model shouldn't be too complex.

Comment: thanks. I have about 100 groups with less than 5 docs, won't be possible to address all of those manually. Need an automated solution.